ESP-IDF: Compiling a ULP module: Tool doesn't match supported version from list ['2.35_20220830']: /usr/bin/cc
I have an esp-idf program with an ULP module like this:
idf_component_register(SRCS "ulp-experiment.c" INCLUDE_DIRS "." REQUIRES ulp)

# a name for the app that runs on the low power chip
set(ulp_app_name lp_core_main)

# sources for the program that runs on the low power chip
set(ulp_sources "ulp/ulp.c")

# sources that run on the main CPU and need to directly include generated interfaces to low power device
set(ulp_exp_dep_srcs "ulp-experiment.c")

# embed the low power program into the main program
ulp_embed_binary(${ulp_app_name} "${ulp_sources}" "${ulp_exp_dep_srcs}")

I am compiling for the esp32c6 chip.
When I build with idf.py build I get:
CMake Error at /home/alex/code/esp-idf/tools/cmake/tool_version_check.cmake:36 (message):
  Tool doesn't match supported version from list ['2.35_20220830']:
  /usr/bin/cc

  Please try to run 'idf.py fullclean' to solve it.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (check_expected_tool_version)

I've tried running idf.py fullclean as suggest, but it doesn't help. What should I do to resolve this?
Checking the version of /usr/bin/cc gives this:
$ /usr/bin/cc --version                                                                                           
cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I'm not sure why the framework is accessing my regular C compiler. I thought it had its own C compiler for the esp32c6 architecture.
The relevant parts of the build log appear to be this:
[123/274] Building C object esp-idf/esp_lcd/CMakeFiles/__idf_esp_lcd.dir/src/esp_lcd_panel_io_i2c_v1.c.obj
[124/274] Building C object esp-idf/esp_hid/CMakeFiles/__idf_esp_hid.dir/src/esp_hidh.c.obj
[125/274] Building C object esp-idf/console/CMakeFiles/__idf_console.dir/argtable3/arg_rex.c.obj
[126/274] Performing configure step for 'lp_core_main'
FAILED: esp-idf/main/lp_core_main-prefix/src/lp_core_main-stamp/lp_core_main-configure /home/alex/code/maple-gateboard/ulp-experiment/build/esp-idf/main/lp_core_main-prefix/src/lp_core_main-stamp/lp_core_main-configure 


The solution was to run idf.py menuconfig and go to "Component config" -> "Ultra Low Power" and tick the "Enable Ultra Low Power Co-processor" box:

After that it was necessary to run idf.py fullclean
